# Attribute Error running PyTest

Tags: python, runtime-error, pytest

I am currently trying to run some test on a program, but suddenly I keep getting the same error, no matter what I run it on, be it the program I want to test, a basic tutorial file, an empty file or nothing. The error is :

```
  File "/usr/local/bin/py.test", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 38, in main
    config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 117, in _prepareconfig
    pluginmanager=pluginmanager, args=args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 724, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 338, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 333, in <lambda>
    _MultiCall(methods, kwargs, hook.spec_opts).execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 595, in execute
    return _wrapped_call(hook_impl.function(*args), self.execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 249, in _wrapped_call
    wrap_controller.send(call_outcome)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/helpconfig.py", line 28, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    config = outcome.get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 279, in get_result
    _reraise(*ex)  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 264, in __init__
    self.result = func()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 596, in execute
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 852, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    self.parse(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 957, in parse
    self._preparse(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 918, in _preparse
    self.pluginmanager.load_setuptools_entrypoints("pytest11")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 501, in load_setuptools_entrypoints
    plugin = ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2088, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytest_bdd/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pytest_bdd.steps import given, when, then
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytest_bdd/steps.py", line 43, in <module>
    from .feature import parse_line, force_encode
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytest_bdd/feature.py", line 37, in <module>
    from . import exceptions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytest_bdd/exceptions.py", line 65, in <module>
    @six.python_2_unicode_compatible
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'python_2_unicode_compatible'
```

I could not find anything relating specifically to this bug in pytest, although it seems to occur in other programs using the six module. I tried reinstalling both six and pytest, but so far no luck. What is the problem and how to solve it?

Here is the result for `print(six.__file__, dir(six))`:

```
('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.pyc',
 ['BytesIO', 'Iterator', 'MAXSIZE', 'Module_six_moves_urllib',
  'Module_six_moves_urllib_error', 'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse',
  'Module_six_moves_urllib_request', 'Module_six_moves_urllib_response',
  'Module_six_moves_urllib_robotparser', 'MovedAttribute', 'MovedModule',
  'PY2', 'PY3', 'StringIO', '_LazyDescr', '_LazyModule', '_MovedItems',
  '__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__',
  '__package__', '__version__', '_add_doc', '_func_closure', '_func_code',
  '_func_defaults', '_func_globals', '_import_module', '_iteritems',
  '_iterkeys', '_iterlists', '_itervalues', '_meth_func', '_meth_self',
  '_moved_attributes', '_urllib_error_moved_attributes',
  '_urllib_parse_moved_attributes', '_urllib_request_moved_attributes',
  '_urllib_response_moved_attributes', '_urllib_robotparser_moved_attributes',
  'add_metaclass', 'add_move', 'advance_iterator', 'b', 'binary_type',
  'byte2int', 'callable', 'class_types', 'create_bound_method', 'exec_',
  'get_function_closure', 'get_function_code', 'get_function_defaults',
  'get_function_globals', 'get_method_function', 'get_method_self',
  'get_unbound_function', 'indexbytes', 'int2byte', 'integer_types',
  'iterbytes', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'iterlists', 'itervalues', 'moves',
  'next', 'operator', 'print_', 'remove_move', 'reraise', 'string_types',
  'sys', 'text_type', 'types', 'u', 'unichr', 'with_metaclass'])
```

Comment: Same idea, print the 'six' module version and follow reinstall instructions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164045/error-with-crunchbase-api-wrapper-pycrunchbase

Comment: Are you sure you're importing the *correct* `six`? What does `print(six.__file__, dir(six))` (i.e. where is it and what's in it) show?

Comment: Added to the question

Answer (score 1):

The lack of `python_2_unicode_compatible` and the presence of `_iteritems`, `_itervalues`, ... indicates that you are using an old version of Python Six.

Precisely, `python_2_unicode_compatible` was introduced in [September 2014](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/commits/2bf80fb02887d33f53f0b1d2b58529f36b87e566).

You can install a more recent version with `pip` and `virtualenv`.

Comment: Updating Six (with sudo pip install --upgrade six) does not seem to work. Also py.test was working fine until a few days ago so I am not quite sure about a module introduced last year.

Comment: @Slereah: what version are you using? Try `print(six.__version__)`

Comment: Current version is 1.5.2

Comment: @Slereah: well, [as you can see yourself](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six), latest version is 1.10.0 (released today).

Comment: Doing a force-reinstall tells me indeed that the version installed is 1.10.0, but the version used in python is still 1.5.2

Comment: Where is it being installed? Probably `pip` is installing 1.10.0 to `/usr/local/lib`, but python is looking for it in `/usr/lib`. You are not giving me any details, so the only thing I can do here is guessing. But as I said, I strongly suggest you to go with virtualenv, especially if you are having trouble understanding where stuff is getting installed.